# What's a Hex Dump - What does it mean?

Tags: hexdump

```
thegladiator:~/cp$ cat new.txt
Hello World This is a Trest Progyy

thegladiator:~/cp$ hexdump new.txt
0000000 6548 6c6c 206f 6f57 6c72 2064 6854 7369
0000010 6920 2073 2061 7254 7365 2074 7250 676f
0000020 7979 000a                              
0000023
```

How is that text data represented in hex like that? What is the meaning of this?

Comment: This didn't help? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_dump

Comment: What OS? (that might help with why the bytes are swapped)

Comment: @S. Lott: That sounds very close to a LMGTFY answer.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15650/ban-lmgtfy-let-me-google-that-for-you-links

Comment: Ubuntu / Linux . Wiki didnt help me grasp the concepts as much as I wanted . Why H is 48 ? ASCII ?

Comment: @Nishant: Yes, 48 is ASCII for H.  However for some reason your bytes are swapped as KevinDTimm points out.  Don't know why that's happening.

Comment: H is 48 hex (do a man ascii to see why)

Comment: What about the first 0000000 0000010 etc data ?

Comment: @Nishant: Those are the byte offsets in your file.  The first row shows the first 16 bytes, the second row shows the second 16 bytes, etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

it's just what it says, a dump of the data in hexidecimal format:

```
H 48 
e 65
l 6c
l 6c
o 6f
```

It is odd though that all of the bytes are swapped (65 48 : e H)

If you're on a *nix system, you can use 'od -x', or 'man od' will tell you all the ways to get data from od :)

Comment: All of the bytes seem to be swapped, not just some of them.

Comment: This appears to be ASCII encoded text with the bytes swapped for some reason.  See http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: @John: Little-endian has to do with numeric encoding not string encoding.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Comment: Is there an equivalent binary Dump ?

Comment: @Eric If this is the linux `hexdump` then the default output format (which the OP used) amounts to `-x` which displays the data as 16-bit integers.  Hence endianness is an issue.  OP should try with `-c` option to see if the switching goes away.

Comment: @John - this is why I recommend od (besides that it's on 'every' *nix machine whereas hexdump may not be)

Answer (score 6):

The text in the file `new.txt` is stored using [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com) encoding.  Each letter is represented by a number, decimal: 32-127 hexidecimal: 20-7F.  So the first three letters (`H,e,l`), are represented by the decimal numbers: `72,101,108` and the hexidecimal numbers: `48,65,6C`

`Hexdump` by default takes each 16 bit word of the input file `new.txt` and outputs this word as a Hexidecimal number.  Because it is operating on 16 bits, not 8 bits, you see the output in an unexpected order.

If you instead use `xxd new.txt`, you will see the output in the expected order.

Comment: As a pair ? 8bits should be represnted by Hex pair .

Comment: 8bits are represented by two hex digits.  So the 4 in 48 is four bits and the 8 is the other four bits

Comment: `hd` (which is a symlink to hexdump, and causes the `-C` switch to become default) will also produce the expected output.