# Bash : Check if file contains other file contents

Tags: bash, shell, awk, grep, append

So I'm trying to append the contents of one file to another file, if it's not already included. This is how I try:

```
catAndAppendIfMissing(){
    [[ ! -s $2 ]] && touch "$2" || [[ ! -s $2 ]] && sudo touch "$2"
    if grep $1 $2; then
        echo "found"
    else
        catAndAppend $1 $2       #this appends file $1 contents to file $2 (and takes care of adding newlines if needed and uses sudo if needed, thus the separate function)
    fi
}
```

With `if grep $1 $2` I'm trying to see if file $1 contents are present in file $2. That's the part that doesn't work as intended:
When I run this twice on the same file, it will simply append the same text twice to the destination file.

How can I solve that?

---

Precisions:

- I'm on OSX 10.11.5 (but a solution for Linux / cross-platform could also be relevant both for me at home or for someone else reading this)
- My choice of using catAndAppend over `cat $file1 >> $file2` is to handle cases where sudo is needed and separate the appended stuff from what's already there by adding newlines as needed.
- I don't wish to append if file $1 is anywhere in file $2 (not only at the beginning or the end)
- For info, here's one of the files $1 contents that I tried against:

.

```
alias ls='ls -a'
alias mkdir="mkdir -pv"
alias wget="wget -c"
alias histg="history | grep"
alias echopath='echo $PATH | tr -s ":" "\n"'
alias myip="curl -sSL http://ipecho.net/plain | xargs echo"
alias webpic="mogrify -resize 690\> *.png"

alias cddog='cd ~/dev/go/src/github.com/dogtools/dog'
alias xp='cd ~/dev/go/src/experiments'
```

- but I will need to use it with other files containing var exports, code, commands, configs, any kind of text basically

Comment: "if grep $1 $2" should be 'if grep `cat $1` $2'

Comment: `catAndAppend` ? `cat "$1" >> "$2"`?

Comment: `catAndAppend` works with `permission denied` files, and adds a newline after what's appended to accomodate future appends to the same file. That's why I use something custom over `cat "$1" >> "$2"`

Comment: also @BigDataLearner `if grep cat $1 $2` still seems to fail (it always goes into the `else` case and appends whatever the file already contained).

Comment: did you try executing your `grep` line by itself? Get that to work from cmd line before you worry about the other stuff. Grep normally uses words/phrases/regular expressions as its search target and would not try to open `file1` to get all of the "words" inside of it. You might be able to munge the output of `comm` to see that two files are identical. Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

Don't append if file `$1` is *anywhere* in file `$2`:

```
catAndAppendIfMissing(){
    f1=$(wc -c < "$1")
    diff  -y <(od -An -tx1 -w1 -v "$1") <(od -An -tx1 -w1 -v "$2") | \
    rev | cut -f2 | uniq -c | grep -v '[>|]' | numgrep /${f1}../ | \
    grep -q -m1 '.+*' || cat "$1" >> "$2";     }
```

---

How it works:

1. Count chars in file `$1` using `wc`.
2. Use `od` to produce a one byte per line [*hex dump*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5572136/whats-hex-dump-what-does-it-mean) of both files, and using a `bash`ism, obtain a [`diff` file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff_utility#Usage), which is piped to...
3. `rev`, then `cut` the *2nd* field, and do a `uniq` count of the consecutive lines that have blanks instead of '>'s.
4. If one of those counts is equal to or greater than `$f1`, it's OK to append. This could be checked with variables, but [`numgrep`](http://suso.suso.org/programs/num-utils/) was convenient and helps avoid variables.

Notes.  Good: works with binary files too.  Bad: inefficient, `od` reads the whole of both files, and `diff` reads the whole of `od`'s output.  If *file1* was a one line string, which was in the first line of a 1TB *file2*, much time would be wasted.

---

*(Old version).*  Don't append if file `$1` is already appended to file `$2`:

```
catAndAppendIfMissing(){
    f1=$(wc -c < "$1")
    f2=$(wc -c < "$2")
    [ $f1 -le $f2 ] &&  cmp -s "$1" "$2" 0 $(( $f2 - $f1 )) && return 1 
    cat "$1" >> "$2"
    }
```

---

How it works:

1. Get file lengths with `wc`, store in `$f1` and `$f2`.
2. If the first file is *longer* than the second file, (or if shorter, if `cmp` shows the the first file isn't *already* appended to the second file), then append it to the second file with `cat`.  Otherwise `return` with an error code.

Comment: This will only work if `$2` is not smaller than `$1`. And you properly want to change it to: `cmp ... || cat "$1" >> "$2"`

Comment: This works if the string I'm looking for is at the end of the file. If it's anywhere else in the file it's going to append it again

Comment: @n-marshall, the Q being somewhat *append* oriented, it gave the impression that the goal was solely to avoid double *append*ing.  Please consider improving the Q's wording to clarify the point that `$f1` shouldn't occur *anywhere* in `$f2`.

Comment: That's true. I didn't realize it was unclear before. Anyways it's edited now :)

Comment: I finally got the time to try your new solution, but i'm now getting an error : `./common/configs/.shell-functions: line 65: syntax error near unexpected token \`('`

`./common/configs/.shell-functions: line 65: \`    diff  -y <(od -An -tx1 -w1 -v "$1") <(od -An -tx1 -w1 -v "$2") | \'`


I could definitely use some help, as i'm not able to understand that code (yes, even with the explanations ! :) I don't know how you came up with that solution)

Comment: @n-marshall, well it's `bash` code, and that error is what happens if it's run in a shell like `dash`.  To verify, is the first line of the script `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/bin/sh`?  If it's `#!/bin/sh`, what does `ls -l /bin/sh` show?

Comment: @n-marshall, anyway, just change the first line of the script to read `#!/bin/bash`, then try it.

Comment: `-r-xr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  632672 Jan 14  2016 /bin/sh` is what I get when running `ls -l /bin/sh`. I have both bash and zsh installed on my machine. Also, putting `#!/bin/bash` in front of every script that's called here doesn't do it.

Comment: When I say 'every script that's called', this is what I mean : I've got a pre-commit hook that sources a file containing the shell helper functions like `catAndAppendIfMissing` and then uses those functions

Comment: When i run `bash path/to/pre-commit` instead of `sh path/to/pre-commit` I get a different error : `numgrep: command not found`. Which indicates that the syntax is recognized...

Comment: The code needs `numgrep`.  Run `apt install num-utils` to install it.

Comment: Forgot to mention, I'm on osx at work... so no apt get here :(
EDIT: thanks !, `brew search numgrep` didn't give anything but `brew install num-utils` certainly does

Comment: Which takes me to that new error : `od: illegal option -- w`

`usage: od [-aBbcDdeFfHhIiLlOosvXx] [-A base] [-j skip] [-N length] [-t type]
          [[+]offset[.][Bb]] [file ...]`

`od: illegal option -- w`

`usage: od [-aBbcDdeFfHhIiLlOosvXx] [-A base] [-j skip] [-N length] [-t type]
          [[+]offset[.][Bb]] [file ...]`

`Couldn't open file 332../ for reading: No such file or directory`

Comment: OSX is relevant and should be noted in the OP.  OSX uses BSD `od`, (no `-w` option), whereas my code is Linux GNU `od`, (has a `-w` option).  I'll check the [BSD od](http://nixdoc.net/man-pages/FreeBSD/man1/od.1.html) and [Linux od](https://linux.die.net/man/1/od) `man` pages later, and see what the equivalent switch is...

Comment: Question edited. Thanks for your patience and your help.

Answer (score 1):

It probably isn't worth trying to conditionally update the file; just source each file to make sure all the aliases are defined, then unconditionally store the output of `alias` to the file you would otherwise be appending to.

```
source "$1"   # Original aliases
source "$2"   # New aliases
alias > "$1"  # Combined aliases
```

Comment: this file containing only aliases is only one example of a file I want to deal with. I have other files containing exports, functions, configuration files... basically I'm trying to put all the config files of my system on git

Comment: I just chose this example because it has a non-trivial things to deal with, like newlines (`\n` and a literal newline in the file) and all kinds of quotation marks

Answer (score 0):

Line:

```
if grep $1 $2
```

should be:

```
if grep `cat $1` $2
```

OR

```
file1_Content=`cat $1`

if grep ${file1_Content} $2
```

OR

```
file1_Content=`cat $1`
grep ${file1_Content} $2

if [ $? == 0 ];then
  echo "found"
else
  #catAndAppend
fi
```

Comment: I really can't get the syntax `if grep \`cat $1\` $2` to work... I get an output like `grep: invalid option -- '`

Answer (score 0):

So I did my homework and came up with a solution which (almost) fits the bill, with the only difference that it's done in python instead of bash. My python script is then called from bash.

So here's the code :

```py
import re, os, subprocess, mmap, sys, pprint 

def isFile1InFile2(file1Path, file2Path): 
    with open(file2Path) as file2: 
        file2Access = mmap.mmap(file2.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ) 
        file1Contents = open(file1Path).read() 
        if file2Access.find(file1Contents) != -1: 
            return True 
        else: 
            return False 

def appendIfMissing(source, dest): 
    destFullPath = os.path.expanduser(dest) 
    if os.path.isfile(destFullPath): 
        if isFile1InFile2(source, destFullPath): 
            print ('Source\'s contents found in dest file, no need to append') 
        else: 
            print('Source\'s contents cannot be found in dest file, appending...') 
            # append source file to destfile 
            command = ' '.join(['source', './common/configs/.shell-functions', '&&', 'catAndAppend', source, destFullPath]) 
            os.system(command) 

    else: 
        print "destfile not a file yet, copying sourcefile to destfile..." 
        # copy source file to destfile 
        command = ' '.join(['source', './common/configs/.shell-functions', '&&', 'catAndAppend', source, destFullPath]) 
        print command 
        os.system(command)

if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    sys.exit('[ERROR] appendIfMissing.py, line 31: number of arguments passed is not 3')
else:
    appendIfMissing(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
```

And then to call it from bash:

```
appendIfMissing(){ 
    python ./common/configs/appendIfMissing.py $1 $2 
}
```

With the bash function (the one called from python) staying the same:

```
createFileIfMissing(){
    # create file if doesn't exist, with right permission
    [[ ! -s $1 ]] && touch "$1" || [[ ! -s $1 ]] && sudo touch "$1"
}

addNewLineToFile(){
    [[ ! -e $1 ]] || [[ -w $1 ]] && printf "\n" >> $1 || [[ -e $1 ]] && [[ ! -w $1 ]] && sudo bash -c "printf \"\n\" >> $1"
}

catAndAppend(){ 
    createFileIfMissing $2 
    # append stuff to it 
    [[ ! -e $2 ]] || [[ -w $2 ]] && cat $1 >> $2 || [[ -e $2 ]] && [[ ! -w $2 ]] && sudo bash -c "cat $1 >> $2" 
    addNewLineTo $2 
}
```

---

Cons:

- It's not bash. I asked for a bash solution in my question (but really all I care about is to have a solution)
- It's not bash. And as it's intended for system setup scripts, I'd have to install python first for this to work. But I want that eventually installed anyway.

Pros:

- It's more readable / maintainable / customizable than bash IMHO (being a newbie to both of those languages, python is more intuitive to start with)
- It's cross platform

Comment: @agc should I accept this answer or yours ? Mine is python instead of bash and yours is linux instead of osx (which you didn't know at the time sorry)

Comment: also if i can tip you (with SO rep or real money) for the time spent don't hesitate !